# Viewing list of data sets that have been edited under specific ArcSDE Version?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, versioning

I'm wondering if it's possible to list all of the data sets (feature classes, tables, etc.) that have been edited under a particular version in ArcSDE.

A tool that does this would be ideal (I see there used to be one by [NASA](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16977), but it doesn't seem to be working for me in 10.3), but I am also open to any other suggestions, including accessing SDE directly.

And just to be clear, I am *not* looking to compare changes made between a version and the default. I already know how to do that using the "Version Changes" button on the Versioning toolbar in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, tables aren't modified in versions, they're modified in ***states***.  A version is simply a named state (more specifically, it's the *last* state in a chain of states within the state tree).  In order to determine the tables affected by the state lineage associated with a version you'd need to identify all the states in that lineage (which would certainly be easier after a compress), and review the Adds and Deletes tables of all versioned feature classes in the geodatabase for a transaction in those states. It's certainly possible, but rather tedious.  The task would certainly be easier if framed, "Does the table *T* participate in the intermediate state lineage associated with version *V*?" (in fact, this is accomplished by "Version Changes").

Comment: I passed this along to our SDE Administrator, and he found it helpful. Thanks!